# Hawthorn to Ironwood Migration (Open edX)

Tags: python, django, openedx

I am trying to execute database migration from hawthorn.master to ironwood.master, during MySQL migration, getting the error like this:

```
Applying content_type_gating.0002_auto_20181119_0959…Traceback (most recent call last):
File “./manage.py”, line 123, in 
execute_from_command_line([sys.argv[0]] + django_args)
File “/edx/app/edxapp/venvs/edxapp/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/init.py”, line 364, in execute_from_command_line
utility.execute()
File “/edx/app/edxapp/venvs/edxapp/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/init.py”, line 356, in execute
self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
File “/edx/app/edxapp/venvs/edxapp/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py”, line 283, in run_from_argv
self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
File “/edx/app/edxapp/venvs/edxapp/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py”, line 330, in execute
output = self.handle(*args, **options)
File “/edx/app/edxapp/venvs/edxapp/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/migrate.py”, line 204, in handle
fake_initial=fake_initial,
File “/edx/app/edxapp/venvs/edxapp/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py”, line 115, in migrate
state = self._migrate_all_forwards(state, plan, full_plan, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
File “/edx/app/edxapp/venvs/edxapp/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py”, line 145, in _migrate_all_forwards
state = self.apply_migration(state, migration, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
File “/edx/app/edxapp/venvs/edxapp/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py”, line 250, in apply_migration
self.recorder.record_applied(migration.app_label, migration.name)
File “/edx/app/edxapp/venvs/edxapp/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/recorder.py”, line 73, in record_applied
self.migration_qs.create(app=app, name=name)
File “/edx/app/edxapp/venvs/edxapp/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py”, line 394, in create
obj.save(force_insert=True, using=self.db)
File “/edx/app/edxapp/venvs/edxapp/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py”, line 808, in save
force_update=force_update, update_fields=update_fields)
File “/edx/app/edxapp/venvs/edxapp/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py”, line 838, in save_base
updated = self._save_table(raw, cls, force_insert, force_update, using, update_fields)
File “/edx/app/edxapp/venvs/edxapp/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py”, line 924, in _save_table
result = self._do_insert(cls._base_manager, using, fields, update_pk, raw)
File “/edx/app/edxapp/venvs/edxapp/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py”, line 963, in _do_insert
using=using, raw=raw)
File “/edx/app/edxapp/venvs/edxapp/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py”, line 85, in manager_method
return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
File “/edx/app/edxapp/venvs/edxapp/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py”, line 1079, in _insert
return query.get_compiler(using=using).execute_sql(return_id)
File “/edx/app/edxapp/venvs/edxapp/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py”, line 1112, in execute_sql
cursor.execute(sql, params)
File “/edx/app/edxapp/venvs/edxapp/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py”, line 64, in execute
return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
File “/edx/app/edxapp/venvs/edxapp/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/utils.py”, line 94, in exit
six.reraise(dj_exc_type, dj_exc_value, traceback)
File “/edx/app/edxapp/venvs/edxapp/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py”, line 64, in execute
return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
File “/edx/app/edxapp/venvs/edxapp/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py”, line 101, in execute
return self.cursor.execute(query, args)
File “/edx/app/edxapp/venvs/edxapp/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py”, line 205, in execute
self.errorhandler(self, exc, value)
File “/edx/app/edxapp/venvs/edxapp/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py”, line 36, in defaulterrorhandler
raise errorclass, errorvalue
django.db.utils.IntegrityError: (1062, “Duplicate entry ‘0’ for key ‘PRIMARY’”)
```

Here is the application link: https://github.com/edx/edx-platform/tree/master/openedx/features/content_type_gating

In addition, this table has no data.
Can anyone help to solve this?